# How can I create a string that lists out numbers?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a string that lists out the dates of a month. For example, I need to make a string that lists out:

```
dayInDateOfBirthInput: "Day\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31",
```

I've tried doing this

```
[Array(31).keys()].map(x => x+1).join("\n")
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: If you want an array from that string you would need something like split(), or if trying to make that string you just need a simple for loop. You need to expand on what exactly you are looking for and what problems you ran into when trying to solve said problems

Comment: apologies, was meaning for it to be string... I've tried doing this [Array(31).keys()].map(x => x+1) with join("\n")

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include that attempt?

Comment: You need `...` the spread operator. E.g. `[...Array(31).keys()].map(x => x + 1).join('\n')`

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried doing this `[Array(31).keys()].map(x => x+1).join("\n")`

You are very close. [`.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) returns an Array Iterator object. You need to [spread it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create an array.

```js
console.log(
  [...Array(31).keys()].map(x => x+1).join("\n")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code from the comments can be tweaked:

```
Array(31).fill(0).map((_,x) => x+1).join("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```js
const str = 'Day' + Array(31).fill(0).map((x, i) => `\n${i+1}`).join('');

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your example is missing a spread operator.

Might I suggest using `Array.from(...)` (of which the second argument is a map function):

```js
let result = Array.from({length:31}, (_,i) => i+1).join("\n");
console.log(result);

let resultWithDay = `Day\n${result}`;
console.log(resultWithDay);
```

To reverse it:

```js
let result = Array.from({length:31}, (_,i) => i+1).reverse().join("\n");
console.log(result);

let resultWithDay = `${result}\nDay`;
console.log(resultWithDay);
```

Comment: is it better to do this? `const range = (start, end) => Array.from({length: (end - start)+1}, (v, k) => k + start);` and then -> range(1,31)

Comment: You absolutely can do that. Though as far as I'm aware, it's just a matter of preference. I'm not sure if `Array.from()` saves you any iteration or processing over other methods.

Comment: how would i reverse the string using 'Day' + Array(31).fill(0).map((x, i) => `\n${i+1}`).join('') ? I tried 'Day' + Array(31).fill(0).reverse().map((x, i) => `\n${i+1}`).join('') but it didn't work out.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The code in your comment wasn't from my answer (it appears to be from someone else's), so I've used my existing code instead of taking theirs. Your code should work fine, though it's not `Day + (array)` anymore if it's supposed to be reversed, it's `(array) + Day`.